# Is this a good structure for a restapi client?

Tags: api, rest, dart, design-patterns, client

I'm trying to come up with a way to structure a restAPI client so that it is mockable, and easy to read. Preferably the syntax would closely mimic the way restAPI uris are built:

```
GET http://example.com/resource/id/subResource/id
```

In my project there are currently two resources: Plans and Serialnumbers

Plans are the root resource and serialnumbers can be assigned to them:

```
GET http://example.com/plans/id/serialnumbers/id
```

Ive come up with the follow set of classes (the actual HTTP calls to the client have been omitted)

```
abstract class ITrackerApiClient {
  ITrackerApiPlans get plans;
}

abstract class ITrackerApiPlans {
  Future<void> getAll();
  Future<void> create();
  ITrackerApiPlan byId(String id);
}

abstract class ITrackerApiPlan {
  ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumbers get serialnumbers;

  Future<void> delete() async {}
  Future<void> get() async {}
}

abstract class ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumbers {
  Future<void> getAll();
  Future<void> create();
  ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumber byId(String id);
}

abstract class ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumber {
  Future<void> delete();
  Future<void> get();
}

class TrackerApiClient implements ITrackerApiClient {
  @override
  ITrackerApiPlans get plans => TrackerApiPlans();
}

class TrackerApiPlans implements ITrackerApiPlans {
  @override
  Future<void> create() async {
    //httpclient.put(uri)
  }

  @override
  Future<void> getAll() async {
    //httpclient.get(uri)
  }

  @override
  ITrackerApiPlan byId(String id) {
    return TrackerApiPlan(id);
  }
}

class TrackerApiPlan implements ITrackerApiPlan {
  final String id;

  TrackerApiPlan(this.id);

  @override
  ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumbers get serialnumbers => TrackerApiPlan_Serialnumbers(id);

  @override
  Future<void> delete() async {
    //httpclient.delete(uri)
  }

  @override
  Future<void> get() async {
    //httpclient.get(uri)
  }
}

class TrackerApiPlan_Serialnumbers implements ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumbers {
  final String planId;

  TrackerApiPlan_Serialnumbers(this.planId);

  @override
  Future<void> create() async {
    //httpclient.put(uri)
  }
  @override
  Future<void> getAll() async {
    //httpclient.get(uri)
  }

  @override
  ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumber byId(String id) {
    return TrackerApiPlan_Serialnumber(planId, id);
  }
}

class TrackerApiPlan_Serialnumber implements ITrackerApiPlan_Serialnumber {
  final String planId;
  final String id;

  TrackerApiPlan_Serialnumber(this.planId, this.id);

  @override
  Future<void> delete() async {
    //httpclient.delete(uri)
  }
  @override
  Future<void> get() async {
    //httpclient.get(uri)
  }
}
```

This code structure allows me to do things like this:

```
class Test {
  void foo() {
    ITrackerApiClient client = TrackerApiClient();
    client.plans.getAll();
    client.plans.create();

    client.plans.byId("id").get();
    client.plans.byId("id").delete();

    client.plans.byId("id").serialnumbers.getAll();
    client.plans.byId("id").serialnumbers.create();

    client.plans.byId("id").serialnumbers.byId("foo").get();
    client.plans.byId("id").serialnumbers.byId("foo").delete();
  }
}
```

I really like the readability of the client calls. I don't like the number of classes required but on the other hand it's not too much effort. The actual http calls I can either perform in each of those classes, or delegate a call to another "internalApiClient" class which contains methods to perform each of the http calls.

Does this seem like a good idea given the fact that the api will continue to grow and will in the end require many more classes?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to hand-code this? Don't they have an OpenAPI/Swagger document that you can use to auto-generate all the client code?

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but that's not what the question was about. You can assume that the reason is that I want to learn how to create a good rest api client.

Comment: You should create one base abstract class with main methods. And the rest like plans and serial numbers just  implement inside the class. Maybe sometimes you don't need extends your base abstract class for one function.

Comment: @Arnas do you have an example of what you mean? Do you mean one class TrackerApi which has methods like api.getSerialnumberOfPlan(planId) or api.createPlan()?

Comment: @ClaudeHasler I see you use most get, by id, create, get all. Create one abstract class with them and implement with other class. The rest implement without override in the class.

Comment: @ClaudeHasler And abstract classes used most if you need merge service with repository. Maybe in your case you can do all into one class.